# Calling function triggered by event from an external JS file in angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom-events, external-js

I am trying to convert a webpage designed by JS, HTML, CSS into an angular project. I have included the JS file in index.html as given below

*index.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sample</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body class="">
<app-root></app-root>

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/scripts/sample.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*sample.js*

```
if (document.getElementById("fixedHeader")) {
    window.onscroll = function () { fixedHeader(); };
    var header = document.getElementById("fixedHeader");
    var fixed = header.offsetTop;
} 
function fixedHeader() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > fixed) {
        header.classList.add("fixed-active-lob");
        $('body').addClass("fixed-nav");
    } else {
        header.classList.remove("fixed-active-lob");
        $('body').removeClass("fixed-nav");
    }
}
```

*current.component.html*

```
<div class="gb-nav gn">
    <div id="fixedHeader" class="header">....
    </div>
</div>
```

*sample.css* File included in *styles.css* having

```
.gb-nav.gn .fixed-active-lob {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
}
body.fixed-nav{
    padding-top:56px
}
```

I was not able to trigger the function from sample.js in angular component. However I was able to reap the desired result by defining the same function again in the

*current.component.ts* as:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
    scrollHandler(event: any) {
    console.log("Scroll event", event);
    this.fixedHeader();
    }
fixedHeader() {
    var header = document.getElementById("fixedHeader");
    var fixed: number = 0;
    if (header?.offsetTop != undefined) {
      fixed = header?.offsetTop;
    } else {
      fixed = 0;
    }
    if (window.pageYOffset > fixed) {
        header?.classList.add("fixed-active-lob");
        $('body').addClass("fixed-nav");
    } else {
        header?.classList.remove("fixed-active-lob");
        $('body').removeClass("fixed-nav");
    }
}
```

But I would like to use the function from the JS file instead of redoing it in the ts file, please help.

Comment: Export that function from the Javascript sample file making it a module, import that function in the component file, remove the script tag

Comment: @AluanHaddad Can you please share a code snippet or a reference link that I could use since I am just a beginner in angular... Thanks.

Comment: In `sample.js` export like so `export function fixed Header ()...etc`, set `"allowJs": true` in `tsconfig.json`, and import it in your component module for use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, modify `sample.js` such that it exports `fixedHeader` like so

```
if (document.getElementById("fixedHeader")) {
  window.onscroll = function () { fixedHeader(); };
  var header = document.getElementById("fixedHeader");
  var fixed = header.offsetTop;
}  

export function fixedHeader() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > fixed) {
    header.classList.add("fixed-active-lob");
    $('body').addClass("fixed-nav");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("fixed-active-lob");
    $('body').removeClass("fixed-nav");
  }
}
```

With this adjustment, we've made `sample.js` into a module, with a single export named `fixedHeader`, and have thus enabled other modules, such as our `current.component.ts`, to consume it via the standard, explicit, and canonical method for sharing code in JavaScript: Modules.

Next, set `"allowJs": true` in your project's `tsconfig.json`, to inform TypeScript that our project includes a mix of both TypeScript and JavaScript source files.

Finally, import the `fixedHeader` function we've exported from `sample.js` directly into `current.component.ts`, remove the now  redundant method from the Angular component class, and call the imported function as follows

```
 import {Component, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

 import {fixedHeader} from '../assets/scripts/sample.js';

 @Component({
   // Angular boilerplate and ceremony
 })
 export class CurrentComponent { // or whatever it is actually called
   @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
   scrollHandler(event: Event) {
     console.log("Scroll event", event);
  
     fixedHeader();
  }
}
```

Finally, remove the script tag that originally loaded `sample.js` from `index.html`.

Note: adjust import path above as needed based on the actual location of the files relative to one another.

Comment: I know this comment is late but thank you, I was able to go ahead with your method.

Comment: @ArjunP Glad to have been of help. Perhaps mark it is the accepted answer?